# What causes gel'd gas in float bowl?

Tags: carburetor, gasoline, carb-cleaner

The attached picture shows (right float bowl) accumulation after just a week after cleaning and reassembling carbs. Just after opening the bowls, they dried bits seen in the picture were similar to gel blobs.

What would cause this type of coagulation?

The gas in the tank is fresh regular, with Berryman's B12 #2616 Total Fuel System Cleanup added to aid the previous carb issues I thought I might be running into.

[image: Mikuni twin carbs]

Comment: Alcohol in the fuel. Never saw this bullcrap until they started adding alcohol to the fuel.

Comment: when its wet looks like snot...yup that alcohol...i have twin carbs i have to clean out also

Comment: I had that happen once but in motorcycle carbs thst sat for a year in a hot climate..

Answer (score 1):

manufactures of carburetor gas engines such as honda, brigs and straton ,preditor  do not recomend using alchol gas in any of their products as it will void the warranty also kawasaki and other carbed engines do the same..unless your fuel system is setup to use straight alcohol...most all older carbs and many new carbs wont tollerate it...ive seen it many times

Answer (score 0):

I run 100% alcohol and it does not gel or change colors, looks to me like bad/cheap gas. I would clean the system and try a different source for your fuel.